# Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless stopped working after installing updates

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

To be completely clear - I've been successfully using 14.04 for several months now. However, this problem just happened when I installed some routine updates. My computer is an HP Pavilion DV6. There is a hardware button that (until yesterday) turned the wireless on and off. However, it appears to be permanently in the off position.

I couldn't find any solutions so hopefully someone can solve this mystery. I think it must be that somehow the wireless driver got updated and this threw everything off.

Here is the output of `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_usb_audio         153899  1 
snd_usbmidi_lib        29215  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_pcm               102099  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_page_alloc         18710  1 snd_pcm
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
hid_generic            12548  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
usbhid                 52659  0 
snd                    69322  11 snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mac_hid                13205  0 
i915                  784207  3 
video                  19476  1 i915
drm_kms_helper         55071  1 i915
drm                   303102  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23274  0 
psmouse               106714  0 
ahci                   25819  2 
r8169                  67581  0 
libahci                32716  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               46202  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii                    13934  1 r8169
```

Here is the output of `lshw -C network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Ralink corp.
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c2500000-c250ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: a0:b3:cc:48:f1:27
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c2404000-c2404fff memory:c2400000-c2403fff
```

Here is the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:539a]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1839]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
    Region 0: Memory at c2500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

Finally, `rfkill list all` outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device is supposed to work with the driver *rt2800pci*. Let's load it and see if your wireless begins to work:

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
iwconfig
```

Do you have a wireless interface, ideally wlan0? If so, can you connect? If so, let's add the module to the list of drivers that we wish to load automatically on boot:

```
sudo -i
echo rt2800pci  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

If the wireless does not work, look for clues in the log; post them and we'll continue:

```
dmesg | grep rt2
```

Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much! I loaded the driver and that fixed the issue! Could you please explain how you knew what to do? I.e which information told you what was wrong?

Comment: In _lshw_, the device showed as UNCLAIMED and no driver was associated. Since there is a known working driver for your device, simply loading it and forcing it to load on boot is therefore a logical first step. Happy it worked!